# silverstripe-translatable: how to make dataobjects translatable (slideshow)?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am creating a multilingual Website in Silverstripe, the goal is to have the whole content available in three languages. I am using the translatable module, works fine for now.

Some pages contains a slideshow, meaning that I am associating a bunch of images and captions to these pages. Looks like this:

```
class Slide extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Caption'     => 'Varchar(255)',
        'SortIndex'   => 'Int'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'ParentPage' => 'Page',
        'Image' => 'Image'
    );

    public static $default_sort = 'SortIndex';

    public function getCMSFields() {
        // parent::getCMSFields() does all the hard work and creates the fields for Title, IsActive and Content.
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->dataFieldByName('Caption')->setTitle('Titel');
        $fields->dataFieldByName('Image')->setTitle('Bild');
        $fields->dataFieldByName('Index')->setTitle('Reihenfolge');

        $fields->push(new TextField('Caption', 'Titel'));
        $fields->push(new UploadField('Image', 'Profile Image'));

        // Apply Translatable modifications
        $this->applyTranslatableFieldsUpdate($fields, 'updateCMSFields');

        return $fields;
    }
}


class SlideShowPage extends Page {

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Slides' => 'Slide'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $conf = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create(10);
        $conf->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortIndex'));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slideshow', new GridField('Slide', 'Slides', $this->Slides(), $conf));

        // Apply Translatable modifications
        $this->applyTranslatableFieldsUpdate($fields, 'updateCMSFields');

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

I want to make these slideshows translatable as well. Meaning that I want to prepare the slide show once in the primary language, then hit the "create new translation" button, and get the slideshow available in the translated version as well, with the captions ready to be translated (similar as the main text content). According to the [silverstripe-translatable docs](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/blob/master/docs/en/index.md#translating-custom-properties) this shall be possible. I have added these calls to `applyTranslatableFieldsUpdate()` (see in the code above) and added these lines to my _config.php file as well:

```
SlideShowPage::add_extension('Translatable');
Slide::add_extension('Translatable');
```

The table `Slide_translationgroups` is even created successfully and filled with new entries for each translation. But the content of table `Slide` is not copied.

What am I missing?

Thanks!
Sacher

Comment: Just a side note, but shouldn't the `Slide` class have a "has one" to `SlideShowPage` rather than `Page`? It might affect the way translatable works if your relationships aren't configured correctly

Comment: If you want the Slideshow to be the same in all Languages, you could use my module [`translatable-dataobject`](https://packagist.org/packages/bummzack/translatable-dataobject) that provides this functionality for the translatable module.

Comment: @RobbieAverill: You are right, in theory. I tried both and there was no difference, the issue wasn't solved.

Comment: @bummzack: I have seen that too, I had the impression that this was merged into translatable. At least, translatable offers the same functionality now. Please correct me if I'm wrong! Also, I want to have as few dependencies as possible (maintainability), that's why I wanted to try this the latest.

Comment: Doesn't Translatable always create a new DataObject per locale? I always use TranslatableDataObject together with Translatable module when i need different site trees or permissions per locale. Otherwise I prefer the fluent module for simpler multi-language sites.